# Is possible to set an adb command as a variable in batch?

Tags: android, batch-file, adb

i tried to set a variable equal to an adb command but it doesn't work, here is the code

```
set ten=10
set nine=9
set eight_1=8.1
set eight=8
set seven=7
set version = "adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release"
if %ten% == %version% goto :menu
if %nine% == %version% goto :menu
if %eight_1% == %version% goto :menu
if %eight% == %version% goto :menu
if %seven% == %version% goto :menu
```

Can anyone help me to figure it out?

Comment: what is the error you are getting , edit that too

Comment: What's the exact output of `adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release`?

Comment: If you are on Windows it might be absorbed, but beware that regardless of host platform adb returns \r\n line endings which can confuse a lot of unix scripting into thinking there are extra empty lines in the response.

Comment: the output is the version of the device connected to the pc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cmd` is very simple. The `set` command just sets a variable to a string. There are two ways to catch the output of a command into a variable. One involves a temporary file. Writing the output to a file and re-read it:

```
adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release >file.tmp
<file.tmp set /p "var="
echo %var%
```

The other looks a bit more complicated (you'll get used to it) and doesn't use a file:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release') do set "var=%%a"
echo %var%
```

Both versions rely on a command output of one line only (though both can be expanded to iterate over several lines).

Notes:
Don't put spaces around the `=` with the `set` command - they become part of the variable name respectively of the value.

For best practice use the syntax `set "var=value"` (note where the quotes are).
It prevents from stray trailing spaces (hard to spot when troubleshooting) and saves against some "poison characters"

For similar reasons, use the following `if` syntax: `if "%ten%" == "%version%" goto :menu`
Should a variable be empty or contain spaces, without the quotes you'll get a syntax error.