# Batch variable store result from command

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, variables

It seems for me a very simple question, however I am struggling a lot with this and don't find an answer yet.
My aim is to count occurences of a specific string in a file.
I do or try to do this using following command:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=;" %%a in ('path to file with searchstring') do (
   set count=('path to file I am searching in' find /c "%%a")
   if !count! NEQ 0 echo !count!
)
```

Seems straightforward for me however the second line seems to be wrong as the script exits.
I want to save the result of `find`in a var because I only wants to outpout Nonzero resutls.

Comment: 1. Change to outer loop to `for /F "usebackq tokens=2 delims=;" %%a in ("path to file with searchstring") do ( ... )`. 2. The second line should read `for /F %%c in ('^< "path to file I am searching in" find /C "%%a"') do set "count=%%c"`. 3. You should preinitialise the count variable like `set "count=0"`. 4. Type `for /?` into a command prompt window and (re-)read its help...

Comment: thank you @aschipfl that seems to work. can you schortly explayin what ```^<``` does?

Comment: However it seems that there now is a massive drop in runtime adding the seconde ```FOR``` but I will have a try thank you

Comment: Concerning the `^<`: You could do `find /C "search string" "file path"` to get the count of matching lines, but there appears more than just the count like a header; when you use [input redirection `<`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) to provide the file to `find` the pure count is returned; `< "file path" find /C "seach string"`; since the result of that command line is captured by [`for /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) you need to [escape (`^`)](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) the redirection to not become applied to `for /F`...

Comment: Concerning performance: for every line in the file with the search string(s), the inner `for /F` loop iterates once and starts a new command prompt (`cmd.exe`) instance which actually executes `find`; maybe the speed could be increased, but it depends on your data (formats); perhaps you want to [edit] the question and share some sample data for both data files (search strings and text to be searched)?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I mentioned a more detailed look in my question from yesterday:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59968084/batch-write-text-from-file-into-local-variable-error) 
As I have much lines to process I keep this in mind a bit @aschipfl

Comment: Note: this counts the *lines*  that contain the search string, not the occurrences of the search string. If the search string occurs more than once in a single line, they are counted as one (line). Might or might not matter for you, but you should be aware of that.

Comment: Do you want all the occurrences of a string or all occurrences of a substring in strings?

Comment: @Stephan thanks. indeed this is sufficient as the words I am looking for occur only once in a line in a specific location.
One other problem I had that I found out the ```Find```command searches for substring and so also count lines in which the string combination exist inside other words. However I need the EXACT match so to cope with this I am now using this workaround: `findstr /r /c:"\<%%a\>" TlsTrace.txt | find /c /v "GarbageStringDefNotInYourResults"`

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I watnt he occurences of the exact match, so when Iam looking for `RM` the word `RM4` should not be counted

Comment: Where do you take your search string from? Your `for` loop currently searches the file for the second token of *every line*. Is that really what you want to do (if not, what exactly do you want to do)?

Comment: [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59292378/is-possible-to-set-an-adb-command-as-a-variable-in-batch)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) using [findstr](/questions/tagged/findstr), for better word matching, *(It uses the filenames from your previous question)*:

```bat
@(For /F "UseBackQTokens=2Delims=;" %%G In ("classID.txt")Do @(Set "count=0"
        For /F %%H In ('^""%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /IN "\<%%G\>" "trc.txt"^"'
        )Do @(Set /A count+=1)&SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        If !count! Gtr 0 (Echo %%G: !count!)&Endlocal))&Pause
```

Here it is fully parenthesized over multiple lines for you to better understand:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=2 Delims=;" %%G In (
    "classID.txt"
) Do (
    Set "count=0"
    For /F %%H In (
        '^""%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /I /N "\<%%G\>" "trc.txt"^"'
    ) Do (
        Set /A count +=1
    )
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    If !count! Gtr 0 (
        Echo %%G: !count!
    )
    Endlocal
)
Pause
```

And a fully parenthesized example of it outputting the results to a file named `results.txt`:

```bat
@Echo Off
(
    For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=2 Delims=;" %%G In (
        "classID.txt"
    ) Do (
        Set "count=0"
        For /F %%H In (
            '^""%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /IN "\<%%G\>" "trc.txt"^"'
        ) Do (
            Set /A count +=1
        )
        SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        If !count! Gtr 0 (
            Echo %%G: !count!
        )
        Endlocal
    )
)>"results.txt"
```